# retrieve all images with same prefix in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I have almost 1000 images in my drawable folder with naming convention based on their categories as shown below.

- Student_pic1.png
- Student_pic2.png
- Student_pic3.png
- Teacher_pic1.png
- Teacher_pic3.png
- Parent_pic10.png

Now I want to get all the images of student using **Student** prefix. How Can I do that ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Java has FileFilters "Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter. The behavior of this method is the same as that of the listFiles() method, except that the pathnames in the returned array must satisfy the filter. If the given filter is null then all pathnames are accepted. Otherwise, a pathname satisfies the filter if and only if the value true results when the FileFilter.accept(File) method of the filter is invoked on the pathname."

Comment: You did not tell anything about how to retrieve files with a specific prefix. Or where the filter could be used.